# How can I force Proxmox resident set size (RES) memory to return to node?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, memory, proxmox

I am running Proxmox and have noticed that multiple VMs that have Ballooning enabled are reserving memory even after they no longer need it and the nodes RAM usage is above 80%. This is causing other virtual machines to show incorrect RAM totals example a machine with 2GB min 20GB memory is showing as having a total of 10GB with `free -m`

In this example below VM ID 159 is reserving 10.8GB of RAM.
[image]

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/36c888b4ce93df0e74a425878b392733.png]
[image]

How am I able to force the RES memory to be returned to the node? Can it be done manually?

Comment: i belive only a restart would help on the VM, as this is what i did in the past

Comment: The point of ballooning is to return memory to the host once it's not being used allowing for over provisioning but that's not happening as it's reserving memory in this case 10GB when it should reserve only 2GB max unless it's actually being used but from the graph above you can see it doesn't need the RAM currently. It stays like this until I power off/on the VM.

Comment: yes that's a bad, but normal behavior on proxmox, that's why I not use it anymore, I fixed the amount and the issue is also gone. Sadly I know :(

Comment: So this is ballooning issue is just Proxmox? Because I read the kernel decides this. I am open to switching to OpenStack

Comment: well, I suggest you that your question is better suited on the forums of proxmox as the community and development is great on that specific product. I always use it in case of special needs